# Is Codex 632 on topic on SFF:SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

> "*Who was the enigma the world knows as Christopher Columbus . . . and
>   why has his true identity been covered up for centuries?*
>
> *When an aged scholar is found mysteriously dead in his hotel room, Thomas Noronha, expert cryptographer and professor of history, is
>   called upon to finish the man's unresolved investigation. In the
>   course of unraveling the puzzles and cryptograms shrouding his late
>   predecessor's work, Thomas discovers a code that will set him on a
>   breathtaking race across the globe from Lisbon to Rio to New York and
>   Jerusalem as he is drawn into one of the greatest mysteries of all
>   time, a shocking revelation that will alter everything we've always
>   believed about one of the world's most celebrated adventurers."*"

**Is [Codex 632](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1016753.Codex_632) on topic on SFF:SE?**

Comment: Why the downvote? For context, see this [Meta Stack Exchange Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281893/i-have-a-question-i-think-is-fit-for-scifi-se-but-its-not-among-tags-what-now)

Comment: Other than that, I don't think it is because reviews do not show anything along the lines of Science fiction or Fantasy

Comment: @Aegon - Downvotes on Meta don't mean the same as on the main site. Here they're used as both "*I don't agree*" or "*I don't agree that this question should be asked*".

Answer (score 8):

### No. This novel isn't on topic on SFF:SE.

---

### Conceit

Heavily inspired by the Da Vinci Code, this novel is a mixture of history,  historical fiction and straight-up action. The main character travels from location to location so that he can find and 'decrypt' various historical documents in order to determine Columbus' true identity (spoiler, it's

> Bruce Wayne

Although the book makes heavy reference to Kaballah and various religious myths there's nothing in it that would seem to fall into the realms of alternate history, magic, magical fantasy or science fiction.

### Marketing

The book is [marketed by its publisher](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Codex-632-Secret-Christopher-Columbus/dp/0061173193) as

> Historical Fiction
>
> Historical Contemporary Fiction
>
> [General Fiction](https://www.harpercollins.com/9780061173196/codex-632)

Comment: I can't tell if that spoiler is true or not...

Comment: @DrRDizzle - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpIQQeL2ZYk

Answer (score 6):

Knowing nothing about *Codex 632* and basing my answer solely on this description - **no, it isn't**.

Nothing in that description seems to hint towards aspects that could be considered science fiction or fantasy, so unless the "shocking revelation" ends up being something like "Christopher Columbus was an alien" or "Christopher Columbus is magic", I wouldn't consider it on-topic here - and even then, it might be up for debate.